# How to get multiple response with different mediatype in response body of fastapi swagger?

Tags: python, swagger, fastapi

I have the below code which responds an image as output in the response body. I have 2 list files also (`points1= [[None]*10] * 3`, `points2= [[None]*10] * 6`).

```
@app.post("/imagePath")
async def Infer(image: UploadFile = File(...), img_show: bool = True, points_show: bool = False):
    contents = await image.read()
    nparr = np.fromstring(contents, np.uint8)
    canvas, points1, points2 = infer(nparr)

    elif img_show:
        return StreamingResponse(io.BytesIO(cv2.imencode('.jpg', canvas)[1].tobytes()), media_type='image/jpeg' )
    elif points_show:
        return (({'keypoints1' : {'Body{}'.format(i + 1): points1[i] for i in range(len(points1))}}), 
            ({'keypoints2' : points2}))
```

This code is work well. but I wanna add a condition that in its response show both image and points. As following :

```
@app.post("/imagePath")
async def Infer(image: UploadFile = File(...), img_show: bool = True, points_show: bool = False):
    contents = await image.read()
    nparr = np.fromstring(contents, np.uint8)
    canvas, points1, points2 = infer(nparr)

    if img_show and points_show:
        return ....

    elif img_show:
        
        return StreamingResponse(io.BytesIO(cv2.imencode('.jpg', canvas)[1].tobytes()), media_type='image/jpeg' )
    elif points_show:
        return (({'keypoints1' : {'Body{}'.format(i + 1): points1[i] for i in range(len(points1))}}), 
            ({'keypoints2' : points2}))
```

Please suggest a way for the `if img_show and points_show:` section.

Comment: So you want to have 1 response? including the points and the image?

Comment: @CharlieV Yes. of course, I want to see an image in swagger not encoded of it !

Comment: Could you solve it?